# Delete double space only in tags

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to remove unnecessary spaces between tags and not all the double space, for example I've this string:

```
"<div  class='anything'       >Here will be a text           or something.</    div     >"
```

The end result needs to be something like this:

```
"<div class='anything' >Here will be a text           or something.</ div >"
```

Even better result will be something like this:

```
"<div class='anything'>Here will be a text           or something.</div>"
```

I want to use preg_replace I've tried to use this code:

```
$html = preg_replace('/ ?> < ?/','><', $html);
```

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Is there really spaces between `</` and `div` in your real string?

Answer (score 2):

I think, the task shoud be divided into a number of replacements:

1. Delete spaces in a closing tag (both after `</` and before `>`.
2. Delete spaces before `>` in the opening tag.
3. Change multiple spaces (in the middle of a tag) into a single space.

So the example *PHP* script, with printout of partial results,
can look like below:

```
<?php
$src = "xx  <div   class='anything'       id='abc'      >Here " .
  "will be a text     or   something.</    div     >";
echo "Source: " . $src . "\n";
// Delete spaces in a closing tag
$src = preg_replace('/<\/ *([a-z]+) *>/i', '</$1>', $src);
echo "Repl 1: " . $src . "\n";
// Delete spaces before ">"
$src = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+?) +>/i', '$1>', $src);
echo "Repl 2: " . $src . "\n";
// Change multiple spaces into a single space
$src = preg_replace('/(?:<|(?!\A)\G)[^>]+?\K {2,}/i', ' ', $src);
echo "Repl 3: " . $src . "\n";
?>
```

A bit of explanation concerning regex #3:

- `(?:<|(?!\A)\G)` - Start either from `<` or from the point where the last
  match ended.
- `[^>]+?` - Match a sequence of chars other than `>`, as little
  as possible. Actually, due to the following part of regex, the
  matched text is the part before multiple spaces.
- `\K` - Forget what has been matched so far.
- `{2,}` - Match a sequence of 2 or more spaces.

Due to `\K`, the only matched text is a sequence of spaces, (within the
tag), which is replaced with a single space.

Note about `(?!\A)` before `\G` in the second alternative: `\G` matches
**either** start of the whole string **or** the end of the last match,
but we want here the match **only** for the end of the last match.
So I added `(?!\A)` - negative lookahead for start of the string, to
disable this variant. Otherwise, this regex would have matched e.g. the
first case of multiple spaces, after *xx* and before the first opening tag.

And another remark, for the case when the source text contains
**multiple** HTML elements - an HTML fragment (as I did in "my" source
text):

When the regex processor goes to `>` source char, terminating the current
tag, it:

- completes matching of `[^>]+?`,
- attempts to match the following token (`{2,}`),
- but because the current character is `>`, it fails.

So it starts the next attempt from looking for the next `<` - the start of
the next tag.

Comment: If you want to avoid the while loop, search [about the `\G` anchor and how to use it](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) to find something between two limits (`<` and `>` here). As an aside, instead of initializing `$count` and using a `while` loop, use a `do...while` loop.

Comment: When you want to preserve something that is matched by the left part of your pattern, instead of using a capture group and a reference in the replacement string, you can use the `\K` feature that removes all on its left from the match result: `/<[^>]+?\K +>/i` => `>`.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I corrected the solution accordingly.

Comment: Well done! You have to add `(?!\A)` after or before `\G` because `\G` matches also the start of the string by default.